# JavaScript: Can you substitute variables into anonymous functions on creation?

Tags: javascript, variables, function, anonymous, substitution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Rather than explaining the question, I'll give an example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i ++) {
  get_node(i).onclick = function() {
    do_something_very_important(i);
  }
}
```

Is there any way to have the value of i substituted into the function upon creation rather than execution?  Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me.  `Upon creation` makes me think you want a static variable.  Your example uses i, where it is part of the loop control structure.  If closures are what you want, that's completely different.

Comment: For many more incarnations of the same question/problem, see the "Linked" section in the duplicate linked by Ian.

Comment: It's true that this has been asked before. However it is very difficult for a newcomer to JavaScript to search for such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but that won't work for the example you provided. You would be having [a very common closure problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3a_A_common_mistake) in that `for` loop.

Variables enclosed in a closure share the same single environment, so by the time the `onclick` callback is called, the `for` loop will have run its course, and the `i` variable will be left pointing to the last value it was assigned. In your example, the `do_something_very_important()` function will be passed the value `100` for each node, which is not what you intend.

You can solve this problem with even more closures, using a function factory:

```
function makeClickHandler(i) {  
  return function() {  
    do_something_very_important(i);
  };  
}

// ...

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  get_node(i).onclick = makeClickHandler(i);
}
```

This can be quite a tricky topic, if you are not familiar with how closures work. You may want to check out the following Mozilla article for a brief introduction:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: Working with Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)

---

**UPDATE:**

You could also inline the above function factory as [@adamse suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646903/javascript-can-you-substitute-variables-into-anonymous-functions-on-creation/3646935#3646935). This is actually a more common approach, but is practically the same as the above:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  get_node(i).onclick = (function(p) {
    return function () {
      // we could have used i as a parameter variable as well,
      // but we're using p to better illustrate what's happening
      do_something_very_important(p); 
    }
  })(i);
}
```

Any yet another solution is to enclose each iteration in its own scope, by using self invoking anonymous functions:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  (function (p) {
    // we now have a separate closure environment for each
    // iteration of the loop
    get_node(i).onclick = function() {
      do_something_very_important(p);
    }
  })(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  get_node(i).onclick = (function(i) {
    return function () {
      do_something_very_important(i);
    }
  })(i);
}
```